# Other counterexample of local global principle except for $2y^2=x^4-17$ in Tate-Shafarevich group

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

$2y^2=x^4-17$ ($1951$, Lind) is a well-known counterexample that violates the local-global principle.

This is an order two elements of $Sha(E:y^2=x^3+17x/\Bbb{Q})$, and it has been proven that the order of $Sha(E:y^2=x^3+17x/\Bbb{Q})$  is exactly $4$.

But what are the equations of the other $2$ non-trivial elements of $Sha(E:y^2=x^3+17x/\Bbb{Q})$ ?

We should look for a curve that has a local solution but no global solution, and where $E:y^2=x^3+17x$ acts simply transitively. Such curves should be of the form $qy^2=x^4-p$ (where $p$ and $q$ are integers), but I cannot figure them(2 curves) out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*. In the proof of Proposition 6.5(a), it notes that for $p\equiv1\pmod8$, the three non-trivial elements of the $2$-Selmer group of $y^2=x^3+px$ are $C_{-1}$, $C_{2}$ and $C_{-2}$, where
$$ C_d : dw^2 = d^2 - 4pz^4. $$
Let $E$ be the curve $y^2=x^3+17x$. Then up to change of variables, the three non-trivial elements of $I\!I\!I(E)$ are represented by the homogeneous spaces
$$ C_{-1}:-w^2=-68z^4+1, \qquad
C_2 : 2w^2 = -68z^4+4,\qquad
C_{-2}: -2w^2 = 68z^4+4. $$

Comment: Thank you very much.I am very happy to have received a response from the author of my favorite book. According to Magma, $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})[2]$ is zero, but for me, $C_{-1}$ seems to have no rational points in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ is trivial implies every $E$-torsor has rational points. But $C_{-1}$ seems to have no $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$-rational points.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to have no $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$-rational points." The word "seems" has no mathematical meaning. If you mean you've searched and not found any, that doesn't prove anything, you might not have searched far enough. OTOH, if you can find a point of infinite order in $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2}))$ that is not twice another point, then mapping it to the $2$-Selmer group should, in principle, let you find a point on the homogeneous space.

Comment: Sorry for inappropriate words I used.
 $Sha(E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})=0$ proves $C_{-1}$ has $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$-rational points. That was only I know. Thanks to your comment, I am encouraged to find rational points in $C_{-1}$.

Comment: Which curve ($C_{-1},C_2,C_{-2}$) is isomorphic to $2y^2=x^4-17$ ?